# Users mess with Clion

Tags: windows-10, clion

I have a problem with Clion:

I was using an administrator account (X) on my pc, and then I create a new account (Y) and gave it administrator power, too.

I am using the Y account and saving my projects in

```
**C:\Users\Y\ClionProjects\**
```

but every file I create is generated in

```
**C:\Users\X\.CLion2016.2\system\cmake\generated\**
```

and in the first line of the .h or .cpp appears the comment

```
*"Created by X the dd/mm/yyyy"*
```

When I run the program, in the run tab it says the documents belong to a directory into X user.

I looked for some option to modify the path or the creator name (i found a question on stackflow where they suggest to press Alt+Enter with the cursor on the comment but it doesn't work for my version).

I unistalled Clion, deleted .CLion2016.2 in X user and then installed again the program.

Now it compiles with the right path but it still writes the "created by X" stuff
and doing some actions requires me to create again the .CLion2016.2

I hope to have explain the problem crearly
Thanks a lot for your help